# What is the minimum distance that should be maintained between parallel electric and data cables?

Tags: wiring, data-wiring

I need to run some electric and data (coaxial, UTP Cat5/6 and phone) wires from one room to the adjacent rooms.

I've read [Can I run CAT5/6 cables parallel to electrical cables?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11492/can-i-run-cat5-6-cables-parallel-to-electrical-cables) but I understand that question deals on whether one could use the same pipe for both electric and data lines.

I will use different pipes/raceways and boxes for AC (10A 220V) wires and data, as follows:

1. A 10m run of AC and data, each in a different PVC pipe along a brick wall covered with cement.
2. A 10m run of AC and data, each in a different wall-mounted plastic raceway.

What is the recommended/required distance between each pipe? between each raceway? Does any of the data wires require a separate pipe/raceway?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.  How exactly is it different from [Can I run CAT5/6 cables parallel to electrical cables?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11492/can-i-run-cat5-6-cables-parallel-to-electrical-cables) Finally, why not run them in the same conduit?

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11492/can-i-run-cat5-6-cables-parallel-to-electrical-cables asks if the wires can be run side-by-side or in a separate conduit. I'm interested on some recommended practice for avoiding electromagnetic interference.

Comment: @ShoeMaker For high speed data the electromagnetic interference from nearby AC wires can seriously impact the data performance.

Comment: @ShoeMaker NEC 800.133 (A)(1)(d) requires that: *communications conductors shall not be placed in any raceway, with conductors of electric light (...), 
[unless] all of the conductors of electric light are separated from all of the conductors of communications circuits by a permanent barrier or listed divider, 
or such conductors are introduced solely for power supply to communications equipment and the power circuit conductors are routed within the enclosure to maintain a minimum of 6 mm separation from the communications circuit*. (But that is **only** a safety requirement).

Comment: The permanent barrier part just means that you would have to use shielded cable, which in my opinion you should use anyways.  You could also eliminate all interference concerns by using optical fiber. Just a thought.

Comment: Revival in case anyone finds this with Google. The 'permanent barrier' requirement means a permanent barrier between the cables. Shielding *DOES NOT count* and is potentially dangerous. Part of the barrier requirement is to reduce the risk of simultaneous penetration of multiple cables in walls (e.g. when nailing something to the wall). A live nail is bad, but a live nail and comms cabling is even worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no code requirements for parallel spacing that I am aware of, but a friend of mine who runs network wiring in a commercial setting, says that with typical line voltage, he tries to keep parallel runs separated by at least 12", and shoots for 18".  (He is currently helping me with the exact same issue in our home office reno).

Comment: I was told a minimum of 12" and if possible when crossing the AC cross at a 90 degree angle.

Comment: The wires can be in contact when crossing at a 90, as long as the insulation is rated for the voltage they can be in the same pipe per NEC 620.36 it is not recommended due to noise but it is done legally all the time.