# What is the right way to run ethernet wiring and electrical wiring in a house?

Tags: electrical, noise

Im currently planning to build a 2nd floor in my home, I already know how to do the electrical wiring design according to the norm, however im wondering if its possible to run the ethernet cables together with the electrical ones, common sesnse says no due to posible noise from the AC lines, however the ethernet works with digital signals so im still wondering if its possible or shouls be done , but i would like to hear some opinions about the topic

I will install little server room in the second floor, in order to have conectivity, IP cameras and a DVR in the near future, everything will be using PoE

Comment: Related http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11492/can-i-run-cat5-6-cables-parallel-to-electrical-cables

Answer (score 0):

If your only question is in regards to pulling CATx cables near Romex/NM cable, then you need not worry *as long as you cross your electrical cables at right angles*. This will minimize the chance of any noise being introduced.

You should not pull Ethernet cables right next to and parallel to your electrical cables.