# Power cables parallel to Cat6 UTP ethernet cables with 100mm gap

Tags: ethernet

At home, the power cables in my hallway are running parallel (for about 4-5 metres) to the **Cat6 UTP** ethernet cables, with a **gap of about 100mm**. One of the ethernet cables will be PoE and the others are non-PoE.

Where one of the non-PoE ethernet cables branches off into the adjoining rooms, they do so at a perpendicular angle over the power cables. The PoE cable will continue to run without crossing over the power cable.

I haven't yet moved into the house, so haven't tested the signal or observed any issues yet.

**Q:** Is the 100mm gap sufficient? Or is this going to present any issues?

Comment: In my house I have ethernet cables running parallel to mains cables and cable-tied together.  There is no problem.  I assume you are using screened cables.

Comment: @Chenmunka What do you mean by "screened cable"? 

Here is a link describing my Cat6 UTP cable: https://www.securiflex.co.uk/cat6-u-utp-colours

Comment: Cat-6 is normally screened to protect against interference.  Most, but not all, data cables are.

Comment: @Chenmunka Do you mean shielded when you say "screened"? If so, no, this is UTP (unshielded twisted pair).

Comment: It'll be fine. No gap is actually required.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/194565/18078

Comment: Ethernet runs at 100-500MHz. Compared to those frequencies, line AC is virtually the same as DC. You don't need to worry about it.