# Would RGB LED strip lights interfere with Ethernet cables

Tags: electrical, led, ethernet

I've read that you shouldn't run your ethernet cables next to your homes power cables because there will be some interference due to the different voltages and magnetic field. Would this also apply if you want to run Ethernet cables close to LED strips?
thanks

Comment: The decent cables should be shielded some what, but it depends on how close is close.  A few inches away probably okay, laying on each other might be another matter.  Electric code does not allow low voltage and high(house) voltage in the same junction box.

Comment: My view (as a communications and networks professional) on most "twisted pair ethernet" interference scare stories is neatly summed up here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/194565/18078

Comment: If running parallel they just need a little separation when run in gutter with power as little as 1/4” metal spacer is normal  twisted pair will reduce problems and if shielded I have run 5E with 480 motor wiring and not had a problem. If the wires are crossing they can be touching with no problems at all even not shielded.